# react-multiselect-checkboxes - how to hide the search box

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

Need to remove the search feature in react-multiselect-checkboxes. Tried isSearchable: {false}, but didn't work. how to hide the search feature in it?

Comment: i think you can't as it's integrated in the library so you will need to change from inside which i totally don't recommend as if you did any change in the node modules it will be deleted , but you can use another lib like , you can use this lib to 
 access the input filed css https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown , or yours if u find away to access the css and then give it css property to disable it

Answer (score 2):

Currently I am using same library and needed the same behavior. Quickly looking at the source code, found this.

`hideSearch: true`

Above parameter will hide the search when dropdown opens. Above code works and has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. Currently, I'm using multiselect-react-dropdown version 2.0.22, and there is no way to do this.
However, there is a workaround. Modifying the CSS and placeholder into a space string (" ") would be best.

Here is my **react jsx code** and its works:

```
<Multiselect
    className="selected-items"
    options={selectedPersons}
    displayValue="personName"
    placeholder=" "
    selectedValues={selectedPersons}
    onRemove={(value) => {
        setSelectedPersons(value);
    }}
    showCheckbox={true}
    showArrow={false}
    closeOnSelect={true}
    hidePlaceholder={true}
/>
```

You will also need to modify the **CSS**:

```
.selected-items .optionListContainer {
    display: none !important;
}
.selected-items .searchBox {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```